# Using expr to double a single integer argument

Tags: linux, shell, unix

An example would be

```
$ twice 15<br>
30<br>
$twice 0<br>
0<Br>
$
```

I understand that the basic of expr is

```
expr arg1 * arg2
```

What if I want to specify `arg1` as 2 and `arg2` as whatever the user types.

But I cant seem to make the program run, always a syntax error.
I use `vi` editor to make a new file and put the expr code in the file called (twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell you need to escape the *-operator:

```
expr 2 \* 15
```

otherwise bash will replace it.

And in a script called twice.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `expr 2 \* $1`
```

can then be called like this (after chmod 755 twise.sh)

```
./twice.sh 15
```

to print out 30.

Comment: Thank you very much.
What I needed to do was add the echo to the program.
I did remember to keep the * in '' or in front of a \
but did not remember to inclose everything in ``
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expr "$1" "*" "2";
```